# How can Iaunch a Windows partition in VirtualBox that already exists on my machine?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, kubuntu

I have installed VirtualBox and I would like to have a Windows session from within my Kubuntu session. I have my hard drive partitioned so as to contain both OS. However, VirtualBox seems to only suport OS installed from scratch. Whenever I launch a Virtual Session, it prompts me to insert installation mediums. I have looked into the docs and it similarly details how to launch a VM and then prompts you to install an OS.

So my question is, if I already have an OS installed on a different partition on the same hard drive, how can I go about associating that partition with a virtual session? Is it as simple as copying the entire OS (which I seem to have access to from within Kubuntu session) into the Virtual Box directory containing the "Windows Session" I have created within Virtual Box?

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox.org has a very long answer to this question - it is not always easy, because your existing installation in dependant upon hardware which will not be present in the virtual machine.  The hardware is not missing, but the concept of a virtual machine means that the hardware will be replace with emulations of hardware, probably different than what you machine physically contains.

The answer to how to do this is far to long to type here.  You will need to research this yourself, at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows